# How to login to node.js server using basic authentication?

Tags: node.js

This is my js code to login to a node.js server:

```
$.get("http://localhost/login", { user: 'abc', pass: '123' }, function(sessionId)  
{  
    document.location.href = "info.html?sessionId=" + sessionId;  
});
```

How should I send user-pass to the server using basic authentication?

Comment: This is not a node.js question as much as a jQuery question -- it's Basic authentication, no matter what server is on the other end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Basic Auth and Jquery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)